# How to create audio foreground notification from recyclerview. any class

Tags: java, android, audio, android-recyclerview

I hope you are all well. I've been having trouble with creating a notification service.

I have an audio app with recyclerviews and it's adapter class containing the viewholders. From the onBindviewholder I created an onclicklistener method that opens a player activity.

What I would like to happen is when you click on any item of the recyclerview, it starts the audio together with the foreground notification.

Please give your answers in written code as I am a novice in code jargon.
Thanks in advance.

Here's my code :
Player activity

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    
    TextView song_name, duration_played, total_duration;
    ImageView  nextbtn,prevbtn,shufflebtn,repeatbtn;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    FloatingActionButton playpausebtn;
    Uri uri;
    int position=-1;
   int finalTime;
    private cardhelper currentItem;
    static MediaPlayer mMediaplayer;
   static List<cardhelper>macam = new ArrayList<>();
   private Handler handler = new Handler();
   private Thread playThread, prevThread,nextThread;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        initViews();
        getIntentMethod();
        song_name.setText(macam.get(position).getSurah());
        mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mMediaplayer!=null && fromUser){
                    mMediaplayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mMediaplayer!=null){
                    int mCurrentposition = mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
                    seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentposition);
                    duration_played.setText(formattedTime(mCurrentposition));

                    finalTime = mMediaplayer.getDuration()/1000;
                    total_duration.setText(formattedTime(finalTime));

                }


                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
        shufflebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(shuffleboolean){
                    shuffleboolean=false;
                    shufflebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shuffle);
                }else{
                    shuffleboolean=true;
                    shufflebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shuffle_on);
                }
            }
        });
        repeatbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(repeatBoolean){
                    repeatBoolean=false;
                    repeatbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_repeat);
                }else{
                    repeatBoolean=true;
                    repeatbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_repeat_on);
                }
            }
        });
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        playThreadbtn();
        nextThreadbtn();
        prevThreadbtn();
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void playThreadbtn() {
        playThread= new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                playpausebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        playpausebtnClicked();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        playThread.start();
    }

    private void playpausebtnClicked() {
        if(mMediaplayer.isPlaying()){
            playpausebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            mMediaplayer.pause();
            seekBar.setMax(mMediaplayer.getDuration()/1000);
            Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mMediaplayer!=null){
                        int mCurrentposition = mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentposition);


                    }


                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });

        }else{
            playpausebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
            mMediaplayer.start();
            seekBar.setMax(mMediaplayer.getDuration()/1000);
            Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mMediaplayer!=null){
                        int mCurrentposition = mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentposition);


                    }


                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void nextThreadbtn() {
        nextThread= new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                nextbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        nextbtnClicked();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        nextThread.start();

    }

    private void nextbtnClicked() {
        if(mMediaplayer.isPlaying()){
            mMediaplayer.stop();
            mMediaplayer.release();
            if(shuffleboolean && !repeatBoolean){
                position= getRandom(macam.size() - 1);
            }
            else if (! shuffleboolean && ! repeatBoolean){
                position=((position + 1)% macam.size());
            }
            //else  position will be position..

           int cardhelper= macam.get(position).getAudio();
           mMediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), cardhelper);
            song_name.setText(macam.get(position).getSurah());
            seekBar.setMax(mMediaplayer.getDuration()/1000);
            Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mMediaplayer!=null){
                        int mCurrentposition = mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentposition);


                    }


                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });
            mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            playpausebtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
            mMediaplayer.start();

        }else {
            mMediaplayer.stop();
            mMediaplayer.release();
            if(shuffleboolean && !repeatBoolean){
                position= getRandom(macam.size() - 1);
            }
            else if (! shuffleboolean && ! repeatBoolean){
                position=((position + 1)% macam.size());
            }

            int cardhelper= macam.get(position).getAudio();
            mMediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), cardhelper);
            song_name.setText(macam.get(position).getSurah());
            seekBar.setMax(mMediaplayer.getDuration()/1000);
            Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mMediaplayer!=null){
                        int mCurrentposition = mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentposition);

                    }

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });
            mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            playpausebtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
    }

    private int getRandom(int i) {
        Random random = new Random();

        return random.nextInt(i+ 1);
    }


    private void prevThreadbtn() {
        prevThread= new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                prevbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        prevbtnClicked();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        prevThread.start();
    }

    private void prevbtnClicked() {
        if(mMediaplayer.isPlaying()){
            mMediaplayer.stop();
            mMediaplayer.release();
            position=((position-1) < 0 ? (macam.size() -1 ): (position - 1));
            int cardhelper= macam.get(position).getAudio();
            mMediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), cardhelper);
            song_name.setText(macam.get(position).getSurah());
            seekBar.setMax(mMediaplayer.getDuration()/1000);
            Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mMediaplayer!=null){
                        int mCurrentposition = mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentposition);


                    }


                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });
            mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            playpausebtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
            mMediaplayer.start();

        }else {
            mMediaplayer.stop();
            mMediaplayer.release();
            position=((position-1) < 0 ? (macam.size() -1 ): (position - 1));
            int cardhelper= macam.get(position).getAudio();
            mMediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), cardhelper);
            song_name.setText(macam.get(position).getSurah());
            seekBar.setMax(mMediaplayer.getDuration()/1000);
            Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mMediaplayer!=null){
                        int mCurrentposition = mMediaplayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentposition);


                    }


                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });
            mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            playpausebtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
    }

    private String formattedTime(int mCurrentposition) {
        String totalout = "";
        String totalNew = "";
        String seconds = String.valueOf(mCurrentposition % 60);
        String minutes = String.valueOf(mCurrentposition / 60);

        totalout = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        totalNew = minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
        if(seconds.length() == 1){
            return totalNew;
        }

        else {
            return totalout;
        }
    }

    private void getIntentMethod() {
       position= getIntent().getIntExtra("position",-1);
        macam=cardalbums;
        macam=malbie;

        if(macam!=null ){
            playpausebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
            currentItem = cardalbums.get(position);
            currentItem = malbie.get(position);
        }
        if(mMediaplayer!=null){
            mMediaplayer.stop();
            mMediaplayer.release();
            mMediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),currentItem.getAudio());
            mMediaplayer.start();

        }else{
            mMediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),currentItem.getAudio());
            mMediaplayer.start();
        }

        seekBar.setMax(mMediaplayer.getDuration()/ 1000);




    }

    private void initViews() {
        song_name=findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        duration_played=findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
        total_duration=findViewById(R.id.textTotalTime);
        nextbtn=findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        prevbtn=findViewById(R.id.buttonPrevious);
        shufflebtn=findViewById(R.id.buttonShuffle);
        repeatbtn=findViewById(R.id.buttonRepeat);
        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.playerSeekbar);
        playpausebtn=findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        nextbtnClicked();
        if(mMediaplayer!=null){
            int cardhelper= macam.get(position).getAudio();
            mMediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), cardhelper);
            mMediaplayer.start();
            mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }
    }


}
```

Fragment Adapter Class

```
public class musicadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<musicadapter.cardViewHolder>implements Filterable {

     List<cardhelper> mcardalbums;

    List<cardhelper>filteredData;
    Filter filter;
    int audio;
    int position;
    Context mcontext;


     musicadapter(Context mcontext, List<cardhelper> mcardalbums) {
        this.mcardalbums = mcardalbums;
        this.mcontext=mcontext;
        this.filteredData=mcardalbums;

    }



    @Override
    public cardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_design, parent, false);
        cardViewHolder cvh= new cardViewHolder(v);
        return cvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull cardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        cardhelper currentItem = mcardalbums.get(position);

        holder.surah.setText(currentItem.getSurah());
        holder.count.setText(currentItem.getNumOfSongs());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, Player.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                mcontext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mcardalbums.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mcardalbums = (List<cardhelper>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                List<cardhelper> filteredResults = null;
                if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filteredResults = filteredData;
                } else {
                    filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
                }

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;

                return results;
            }
        };
    }

    protected List<cardhelper> getFilteredResults(String constraint) {
        List<cardhelper> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (cardhelper item : filteredData) {
            if (item.getSurah().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                results.add(item);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }



    public static class cardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


         TextView count,surah;

        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        public cardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_count);
            surah = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_surah);


        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a few weeks of research i found out how to this. Please bear in my I'm a novice but this is what i got from my observation:

1. You don't need a Service Class to create a notification because it can be created anywhere and called from button clicks inside a method. It will obligatorily need a channel, and addAction button to appear:

```
public void showNotification(int playpausebtn) {
        final Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.new_disc);
        macam= (ArrayList<cardhelper>) malbie;
        macam= (ArrayList<cardhelper>) cardalbums;
        if (macam != null) {
            currentItem = malbie.get(position);
            currentItem = cardalbums.get(position);

        }


        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
        previousIntent.setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, previousIntent, 0);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(ACTION_PLAY);
        playIntent.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, playIntent, 0);

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(ACTION_NEXT);
        nextIntent.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, nextIntent, 0);

        // Create a new MediaSession
        final MediaSession mediaSession = new MediaSession(this, "debug tag");
        // Update the current metadata
        mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder()
                .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, icon)
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "Pink Floyd")
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "The Great Gig in the Sky")
                .build());
        // Indicate you're ready to receive media commands:

        Intent intentOpenApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Userxui.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentOpenApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                intentOpenApp, 0);
        // Create a new Notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "CHANNEl_ID");
        // Hide the timestamp
        noti.setShowWhen(false);
        noti.setLargeIcon(icon);
        noti.setVisibility(androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        // Set the Notification style
        noti.setContentTitle(currentItem.getSurah());
        noti.addAction(R.drawable.ic_previous, "previous", ppreviousIntent);
        noti.addAction(playpausebtn, "pause", pplayIntent);
        noti.addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "next", pnextIntent);
        noti.setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                .setMediaSession(MediaSessionCompat.Token.fromToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken())));

        noti.setContentIntent(pendingIntentOpenApp);
        noti.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.only);
        noti.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);


        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Siraa",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            noti.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);

        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti.build());
    }
```

2. To implement notification action button you need to create Strings :

```
public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "action_play";
    public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "action_next";
    public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "action_previous";
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Channel1";
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
```

3.Register these actions inside a Broadcast receiver with intentfilters:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_PLAY);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_NEXT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);

        receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String actioname = intent.getAction();

                if(actioname!=null){
                    switch (actioname){
                        case ACTION_PLAY:
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Click play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           \\\ implement whatever
                            playpausebtnClicked();

                            break;
                        case ACTION_NEXT:
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Clicked next",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            nextbtnClicked();

                            break;
                        case ACTION_PREVIOUS:
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Clicked previous",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            prevbtnClicked();
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }

        };
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

and open themethod in my buttonclick event.
That's it no need to register in the manifest file. Hope this helped.